# R: How do I format a table that I am displaying in an email using sendGrid?

Tags: r, datatable, formatting, sendgrid, formattable

I am using the sendgrid API to send an email with the table in the email body.

Here is a sample code of what I have (using the iris dataset). The output looks like a simple unformatted table, and I would really like to make it more presentable (with table borders and spacing). Any leads on this would be helpful. I am also new to sending emails using sendGrid, so feel free to suggest other methods too.

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
key1 <-  #enter your sendGrid API Key here

from.email <- "abc@xyz.com"
to.email <- "xyz@abc.com"
subject <- "IRIS Report"

colNamesDisplay <- paste("\\n", 
                           do.call(paste, purrr::map(colnames(iris), function(colName){

                                    paste("       ", colName)

                             }))
                          )

body <- paste(colNamesDisplay, 
              "\\n-------------------------------------------------------------------- ",
              do.call(paste, purrr::map(1:nrow(iris), function(rowInd){

                  paste("\\n\\n",  

                        do.call(paste, purrr::map(1:ncol(iris), function(colInd){
                            paste("          ", as.character(iris[rowInd, colInd]))
                        })))

                }))
            )

msg <- sprintf('{\"personalizations\":
        [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"%s\"}]}],
          \"from\": {\"email\": \"%s\"},
          \"subject\": \"%s",
          \"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\",
          \"value\": \"%s\"}]}', to.email, from.email, subject, body)

sendResponse <- POST("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
                      body = msg, 
                      config = add_headers("Authorization" = sprintf("Bearer %s", key1),
                               "Content-Type" = "application/json"),
                      verbose())
```

I get the following table in my email:

Sepal.Length         Sepal.Width         Petal.Length

---

```
        5.1            3.5            1.4        

        4.9            3            1.4          

        4.7            3.2            1.3
```

I would prefer something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxgqW.png]

Comment: Could you expand on your question, e.g. show (a subset of) the output you got and hand-edit it to show what you would like?  I can't run your code as I'm not authorized to use `sendgrid.com`.  Also, what are your constraints?  You'll get nicer looking tables if they include HTML formatting, but if plain text is all you've got, it's still possible to do better.

Comment: @user2554330 - Just updated the question, let me know if you were looking for something else. Also, I am not sure of the HTML syntax to format a table with spacing and borders, so if you have any examples that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `knitr::kable` together with some of the formatting options in the `kableExtra` package to get a formatted table.  For example, this code:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
html <- kable(iris[1:3, 1:3], format = "html") %>% 
  column_spec(1:3, border_right = TRUE, border_left = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(3, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
cat(html)
```

will print as HTML that produces this table:

[image: screenshot]

You can play with the styling to make things fancy if you want.  The likely main issue is that since `kable` and `kableExtra` are designed to work in R Markdown, you may have to do some work to get extra CSS code and Javascript into your email.

Comment: Thank you. I have used formattable and kable before in RMD and RShiny apps, but was unable to use them directly in my specific context involving automated emails. I will have to do some research on CSS and Javascript.